How to setup ActiveMQ broker for multiple Testcontainers
I am trying to setup testcontainers with ActiveMQ broker.
Here's my setup, this is the base test class, that other tests inherit from:
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
abstract class BaseIntegrationTest {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        val activeMQContainer: GenericContainer<*> = GenericContainer("rmohr/activemq:5.15.9")
            .withExposedPorts(61616)
            .waitingFor(Wait.forListeningPort())

        @JvmStatic
        @BeforeAll
        fun setup() {
            activeMQContainer.start()
            System.setProperty(
                "jms.activemq.brokerUrl",
                "tcp://${activeMQContainer.host}:${activeMQContainer.getMappedPort(61616)}"
            )
        }

        @JvmStatic
        @AfterAll
        fun tearDown() {
            activeMQContainer.stop()
        }
    }
}

And here is the test jmsTemplate config:
@Configuration
@Profile("test")
class TestJmsConfig(
    @Value("\${jms.activemq.brokerUrl}") private val brokerUrl: String
) {
    @Bean
    fun connectionFactory(): ConnectionFactory {
        return ActiveMQConnectionFactory().apply {
            brokerURL = brokerUrl
        }
    }

    @Bean
    fun jmsTemplate(connectionFactory: ConnectionFactory): JmsTemplate {
        return JmsTemplate(connectionFactory)
    }
}

Here you can see the full setup: https://github.com/nietup/tcproblem
I get the following error on the failing test:
jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Request processing failed: org.springframework.jms.UncategorizedJmsException: Uncategorized exception occurred during JMS processing
...
Caused by: jakarta.jms.JMSException: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://localhost:32769. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
...

Having one test class seems to be working,
but the tests break when I have 2 test classes.
If I removed one of the test classes, the other one would pass.
I have set up simple tests like this:
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class NiceControllerIntegrationTest : BaseIntegrationTest() {

    @Autowired
    lateinit var mockMvc: MockMvc

    @Test
    fun `send nice message`() {
        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/v1/nice/send"))
    }
}

where calling this endpoint triggers a message to be send to an ActiveMQ queue
And I expect them to pass. But when there is more than one test class, I get an error as described above
In my pom I am using

Spring Boot version 3.2.5
java version 21
kotlin version 2.0.0


Why aren't you just using the Spring Boot testcontainers support which does all of this for you?

Check Testcontainers docs https://java.testcontainers.org/test_framework_integration/manual_lifecycle_control/#singleton-containers You can also combine it with @AutoClose from JUnit 5.11

@m-deinum I am not using Spring Boot annotations, because I want my ActiveMQ container to be shared across several test classes
